# "По смыслу уголовного законодательства" — вводное сочетание или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

"По смыслу уголовного законодательства" … считается ли фраза вводной для постановки запятой?

Comment: Для ответа недостаточно контекста.

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос из 2012 года, привет первым участникам форума.**  А в 2018 году можно на него ответить, достаточно ли контекста?

1) **Да, это не вводное слово,** но вопрос об обособлении обстоятельственного оборота (со значением соответствия) не отменяется.

2) По общим правилам обособление оборота **факультативно**, на выбор решения влияют такие факторы, как позиция оборота, его распространенность, а также желание автора выделить оборот, если это позволяет структура.

3) **Если оборот стоит в начале предложения,** то он обычно является детерминантом, отнесенным ко всему предложению, и не обособляется. В других случаях возможны оба варианта (с обособлением и без обособления).

4) Примеры (использован оборот ***по смыслу закона***):

**По смыслу закона** надомники сами определяют режим работы, и это является главны фактором нашего предложения. [Проблемы правового обеспечения дистанционного управления трудовыми процессами (2004) /, 2004.11.15]

...я вместе с тем запросил мнение прокурора  о том, кому **по смыслу закона** должны принадлежать эти деньги. [А. Ф. Кошко. Очерки уголовного мира царской России. 2 (1928)]

Так, удалось отменить пресловутый реестр монополистов, который, **по смыслу закона,** призван был упростить влияние ФАС на зарвавшихся монополистов или тех, кто доминирует своим положением. [Повестка дня // «Эксперт», 2014]

Слова мои будут простым извещением, которое, **по смыслу закона**, обязательно для всякого верноподданного… [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Губернские очерки (1856-1857)]

Личный собственник, **по смыслу закона**, властен распоряжаться своей землей, властен закрепить за собой свою землю ...[П. А. Столыпин.  Речь в Государственной думе 5 декабря 1908 года (1908)]

Answer (score 0):

Контекста, конечно, маловато, но, думаю, нет, оно не является вводным, так как сомневаюсь, что словами *"по смыслу..."* может выражаться источник сообщения.